# Concatenating strings containing many quotations results in slashes in output

Tags: python, python-2.7, arcgis

I am trying to build a string that needs to contain specific double and single quotation characters for executing a SQL expression.

I need my output to be formatted like this:

```
" "Full_Stree" = 'ALLENDALE RD' "
```

where the value of ALLENDALE RD will be a variable defined through a For Loop. In the following code sample, the variable tOS is what I am trying to pass into the query variable.

```
tOS = "ALLENDALE RD"
query = '" "Full_Stree" = ' + "'" + tOS + "' " + '"'
```

and when I print the value of query variable I get this output:

```
'" "Full_Stree" = \'ALLENDALE RD\' "'
```

The slashes are causing my query to fail. I also tried using a modulus operator to pass the value of the tOS variable, but get the same results:

```
where = '" "Full_Stree" = \'%s\' "' % (tOS)
print where
'" "Full_Stree" = \'ALLENDALE RD\' "'
```

How can I get my string concatenated into the correct format, leaving the slashes out of the expression?

Comment: Those are escape characters, they are escaping your single quotes

Comment: The field name needs to be contained in double quotes and the value needs to be contained in single quotes...

Comment: The print in your last code block gives the desired result for me.

Comment: You're right...why did I get the results with the slashes?! Hmm....

Comment: Is this for an SQL query? If so, parameters will make this easier.

Comment: As you found, passing parameters this way is awkward. More importantly [**it exposes you to SQL injection attacks**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Please learn to pass parameters to your SQL correctly

Comment: To amplify what @JohnLaRooy-AKAgnibbler said: DO NOT DO THIS. This is the path of sadness and despair. When dealing with SQL, *always* use parameterized queries. SQL from string concatenation: not even once.

Comment: Seeing as I'm using this to update values in a standalone table in GIS software, I'm not too concerned with being exposed to SQL injection attacks...or any attacks at all. I just need to update my table's values.

Answer (score 2):

What you are seeing is the [`repr`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#func-repr) of your string.

```
>>> s = '" "Full_Stree" = \'ALLENDALE RD\' "'
>>> s       # without print console displays the repr
'" "Full_Stree" = \'ALLENDALE RD\' "'
>>> print s # with print the string itself is displayed
" "Full_Stree" = 'ALLENDALE RD' "
```

Your real problem is the extra quotes at the beginning and end of your where-clause.

This

```
query = '" "Full_Stree" = ' + "'" + tOS + "' " + '"'
```

should be

```
query = '"Full_Stree" = ' + "'" + tOS + "'"
```

It is more clearly written as

```
query = """"Full_Stree" = '%s'""" % tOS
```

The [ArcGis docs](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//002z0000001r000000) recommend something more like this

```
dataset = '/path/to/featureclass/shapefile/or/table'
field = arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(dataset, 'Full_Stree')
whereclause = "%s = '%s'" % (field, tOS)
```

`arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters` makes sure that the field name includes the proper quoting style for the dataset you are using (some use double-quotes and some use square brackets).

Comment: Yes this was the issue. It seems, however, that when I pass that value as the expression, it still fails. Is there a way to tell python to ignore those slashes and send the expression without the slashes?

Comment: @csterling: If you pass a string to a function just the string is passed, not its repr. I believe your problem lies elsewhere; however, the best way to solve this will be not to solve it at all. Just use a parameterized statement. Follow the link in my updated answer to see how to do this.

Comment: That doesn't exactly work for my needs. I'm using the SQL query to select features and update a standalone table in GIS software.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow the way I already tried worked out:

```
where = '" "Full_Stree" = \'%s\' "' % (tOS)
print where
'" "Full_Stree" = \'ALLENDALE RD\' "'
```

Comment: You can still use + to concentrate strings.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just use triple quotes?

```
a=""" "Full_Street" = 'ALLENDALE RD' """
print a

"Full_Street" = 'ALLENDALE RD'
```

Comment: I need the value of ALLENDALE RD to be a variable. How can I do that with triple quotes?